# how can I increase hdfs capacity

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I increase the configured capacity of my hadoop DFS from the default 50GB to 100GB?

My present setup is hadoop 1.2.1 running on a centOS6 machine with 120GB of 450GB used.  Have set up hadoop to be in psudodistributed mode with the /conf  suggested by "Hadoop the Definitive Guide 3'rd). 
hdfs-site.xml had only one configured property:

```
   <configuration>
    <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
     </property>
 </configuration>
```

The following line gave no error feedback... comes back to the prompt.

```
hadoop dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 100g  /tmp/hadoop-myUserID
```

If I am in a regen loop (have executed

```
 rm -rf /tmp/hadoop-myUserId
```

in a attempt to "start from scratch")  This seeming success of the setSpaceQuota occurs iff-and-only-if  I have executed

```
  start-all.sh
  hadoop namenode -format
```

The failure of my dfs capacity configuration is shown by

```
 hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

which shows the same 50GB of configured capacity.

I would be willing to switch over to hadoop 2.2 (now stable release) if that is the current best way to get 100GB hdfs configured capacity. 
  Seems like there should be a configuration property for hdfs-site.xml which would allow me to use more of my free partition.

Comment: what does your local linux filesystem table look like?  what's the value of dfs.datanode.data.dir in hdfs-site?  make sure the local linux partition that is configured to host the data directory has >50GB of space in it.

Answer (score 5):

Set the location of the hdfs to a partition with more free space.
For hadoop-1.2.1 this can be done by setting the hadoop.tmp.dir in 
hadoop-1.2.1/conf/core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
   <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/myUserID/hdfs</value>
    <description>base location for other hdfs directories.</description>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Running

`df`

had said my _home partition was my hard disk, minus 50GB for my /
( _root) partition.   The default location for hdfs is
/tmp/hadoop-myUserId
which is in the / partition.  This is where my initial 50GB hdfs size came from.

Creation and confirmation of the partition location of a directory for the hdfs was accomplished by

```
mkdir ~/hdfs
df -P ~/hdfs | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

successful implementation was accomplished by

```
stop-all.sh
start-dfs.sh
hadoop namenode -format
start-all.sh
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

which reports the size of the hdfs as the size of my _home partition.

Thank you  jtravaglini for the comment/clue.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all the service: stop-all.sh

then add these properties in terms of increasing the storage size in hdfs-site.xml:

---

```
    <property>
        <name>dfs.disk.balancer.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.storage.policy.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
        <value>134217728</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
        <value>100</value>
</property>
 <property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
         <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode,[disk]file:///hadoop_store2/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

---

also remember to put [disk] for including a extra disk on folder, [ssd] for dedicated extra ssd drive. always remember to check the "///" triple "/" for the directory pointing.

After that,

format the namenode to get the settings inherited in the Hadoop cluster, by giving a command

hadoop namenode -format
then start the services from beginning:
Start-all.sh

"/* **remember without formating the hdfs the setting will not be activated as it will search for the Blockpool Id (BP_ID) in dfs.datanode.data.dir, and for the new location it will not found any BP_ID.** "/*