# Privileged action exception in Hadoop while setting up data nodes?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have set-up hadoop framework in my mac OS X. Using virtualbox, I installed ubuntu server (one nameNode) and two more ubuntu server to act as datanodes.
I have set up core-site.xml and other configurations correctly to my knowledge. when I start the framework using start-all.sh, everything seems fine. doing `jps` on NameNode and each datanodes shows that the process is active. but on the GUI url, I see that no nodes are live. see the attached image.
Here is the error message from log file:

```
2014-06-23 18:00:01,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070
2014-06-23 18:00:01,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,175 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,190 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,195 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,195 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,198 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,201 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:01,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 10001: starting
2014-06-23 18:00:05,692 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:sridhar cause:java.io.IOException: File /usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
2014-06-23 18:00:05,692 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 10001, call addBlock(/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1288778011_1, null) from 127.0.0.1:56524: error: java.io.IOException: File /usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
java.io.IOException: File /usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
2014-06-23 18:00:06,716 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:sridhar cause:java.io.IOException: File /usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
2014-06-23 18:00:06,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 10001, call addBlock(/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1288778011_1, null) from 127.0.0.1:56524: error: java.io.IOException: File /usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

[image]

PS: I did look for other posts that showed similar errors. I tried them. but not successful

EDIT:

The namenode server does not show datanodes and tasktracker on issuing `jps` command.
The log on the datanode looks as follows: (probably datanode is not establishing connection)

`2014-06-23 17:14:16,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ubuntuhadoop/69.91.135.178:10001. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-06-23 17:14:17,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ubuntuhadoop/69.91.135.178:10001. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-06-23 17:14:18,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ubuntuhadoop/69.91.135.178:10001. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work. Though the solution is trivial, I would like to post here so that others novice Hadoopers might benefit.

1) Have the exact replica of `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` in both master (`nameNode`) and all slaves (`dataNodes`). I thought `core-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` in master does not matter. but it is. They open the port on which they listen to. On these ports, `dataNode` can reach `nameNode`.

2)when you run `jps` on master, you will not see a process (atleast I did not see) for `DataNodes` and `TaskTracker` assuming you did `start-all.sh` from master. The reason is because DataNodes and TaskTrackers threads are processed on different nodes of the cluster (in my case, I had one ubuntu box as master and two ubuntu boxes as datanodes).

NOTE: In my case, I did not make my master to serve as datanode (that is as slave)

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the logs that your master node is not able to connect one of the data nodes(ubuntuhadoop/69.91.135.178:10001).

As an initial test please ssh to data node from the master and see if you can connect with it.
Following link might help in setting up the cluster!!

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Comment: i can ssh to datanode from master without any problem

Comment: The image above shows that the configured capacity of the node is 0kb which is abnormal. You need to set up the hdfs in master and data nodes on drive which have more than 50GB capacity available. You can explicitly specify that by adding the "hadoop.tmp.dir" property in core-site.xml. For more information on this see the post below: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542185/how-can-i-increase-hdfs-capacity)