# how to increase capacity of hdfs in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop2

I've been trying to find how to increase capacity of hdfs in Hadoop 2.7.2 with spark 2.0.0.

I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542185/how-can-i-increase-hdfs-capacity).

But I don't understand it. Here is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>hadoop_eco/hadoop/tmp</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://com1:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>hadoop_eco/hadoop/name</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>hadoop_eco/hadoop/data</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

When I run spark with 1 namenode and 10 datanodes, I got this error message:

> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile:
>   /user/spark/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201611141313_0001_m_000052_574/part-00052
>   is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1638755846_140

I couldn't identify this error, but it may related to lack of disk capacity.

My configured capacity (hdfs) is **499.76GB** and each datanode's capacity is **49.98GB**.

So, is there a method to increase capacity of hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

It is so easy to change the capacity of hdfs.

I tried to change hdfs-site.xml

```
  <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>file://"your directory path"</value>
  </property>
```

and use this command line

`hadoop namenode -format
 stop-all.sh 
 start-all.sh`

finally check your capacity of hdfs using `hdfs dfsadmin -report`

Comment: This does not change the capacity. This creates brand new HDFS from scratch and of course loses all data (or rather, you voluntarily dismiss them).

Comment: If you want to add capacity, you can simply add another data dir(s) and reload the datanode(s). Or, of cource, provision new HDFS datanode(s).

Comment: oh well. Thanks!
could you answer one more question? If you don't mind.
I got a new error message: `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device` 
I checked the space on device using df -hl. but there are enough spaces. I don't know why this error appears to the screen.
Is there problem?

Comment: it seems to me that this exception might complain about free space on a particular machine, not in HDFS. If you still see some free space on your local drive, remember that there is a default 5% of reserved blocks for root; thus, if your app runs under non-root user it might run out of space. Try being more specific about the device.

Comment: Ok I will.
I appreciate your advise!